# Simple jQuery tree trouble with more nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree

This is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rexdefuror/2BPw9/10/).

```
$(function() {
    $('li > ul').each(function() {
        var parent_li = $(this).parent('li');
        var sub_ul = $(this).remove();
        parent_li.click(function() {
            sub_ul.toggle();
        });
        parent_li.append(sub_ul);
    });
    $('ul ul').hide();
});
```

If you want to open the third node you'll notice the problem.
since it toggles everything on each click, so i've tried using
sort of check if it has a parent to only hide children etc, but
it didn't work at all...

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Generally, you should include all relevant code in the question, not link to it externally (future-proofing from "dead-link")

Comment: Doesnt work for me either, jquery is missing.

Comment: that's strange... rechecked it works... try now, i removed version number from link it might be that

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('li').click(function(evt) {                   
        $(this).children('ul').toggle();
        evt.stopPropagation(); //Stop bubbling upwards, so our parent doesnt recieve this click!
    });
});
```

Whenever you click a LI you want to toggle the child. The problem is event bubbling, your click is fired on the inner-most element, but then bubbles up to the parent. Which closes the element, as expected.

Thats why we stop the bubbling before it gets there, so the parent wont get the click and we stay open.